# ClassNotFoundException in Gradle Junit test failure

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I am starting Junits for existing complex  project, we are using gradle. I have added below script in dependencies for junits

```
  dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2')
    testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2')
 }

 test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
    useJUnitPlatform()    

    filter {
      excludeTestsMatching "com.xxx.xxx.*"
      includeTestsMatching "com.xxx.sfTasks.*"
    }
   
  }
```

The line 16 from test class, its a class from main and this test case is for this main class, it looks like test class is not able to access main class at test runtime.
XXXCustomDdExtractTask task = new XXXCustomDdExtractTask();  // Line 16 from test class.

gradle test is failing with below error, please advise.

```
    ERROR:
    > Task :test
    XXXCustomDdExtractTaskTest > test() FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at XXXCustomDdExtractTaskTest.java:16
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at XXXCustomDdExtractTaskTest.java:16***
```